# How Can I Get TempData Object Recognize in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ActionMethod that creates TempData object

```
TempData["Message"] = new Message {Text = txtMessage, Success = false};
```

Then I read the TempData in the view like

```
@{var message = TempData["Message"];}
```

But when I try to use the var "message.Success" the compiler doesn't recognize the property. When I watch the var message and TempData during debug I can see the Object's txtMessage and Success value. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be using the ViewBag for stuff like this. TempData is meant for storing data between separate requests.

Comment: A message may need to survive a redirect; ViewBag data will not.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, *if* the message needs to "survive a redirect", ViewBag won't work. Most likely, it's just being used in the view.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, this is possibly true; I know when I build messaging into my projects, it is often to provide feedback from a request that redirects to the index page, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Interesting. You use the same message in both the view and the controller? For what purpose, might I ask?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, I create the message in the controller, i.e., "The object has been created" or "there was a problem with your request"... then in my layout I look for the `TempData["message"]` and if it exists I make a `div` element with the message inside and use jquery-ui to pop up a dialog if the div exists.  Instant, context-sensitive feedback on a redirect.

Comment: Ahh, so the action issues a redirect to another action, and that action issues a view which uses the TempData from the action which issued the redirect?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Yup.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
@{dynamic message = TempData["Message"];}
```

or

```
@{Message message = TempData["Message"] as Message;}
```

or, if you know it will only ever be a Message

```
@{Message message = (Message)TempData["Message"];}
```

Comment: When I use dynamic it does not allow me to varify message != null

Comment: Well then don't do that. Use the Message class if you have to. That'll work even if it's null.

Comment: When I use dynamic it does not allow me to varify 'message != null' and does not recongize message.Success in a ternary operation. I tried to use message.Equals but that didn't work.       And when I use Message it says it can not convert object to target type Message.

Comment: Didn't realize that was a compile time error. Look back at my example.

Comment: The solution that I finally went with was the second option. I cast the Tempdata but kept the local varible as var and was able to write the ternary operation with Html.Raw and .Equals().  Thank you very much for the quick and detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `TempData` is dynamically typed, so you need to cast it.  However, with an anonymous type, you cannot do that.  You will need to convert your anonymous type to an actual class.

If you don't want to do this, you might be able to use `ViewBag` instead, which is dynamically typed.