# TempData with anonymous type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

How can I retrieve data from `TempData` that contains anonymous type? like that

```
TempData["Info"] = new { Id= 1, Name= "John" };
```

Comment: [How Can I Get TempData Object Recognize in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908189/how-can-i-get-tempdata-object-recognize-in-mvc4). There's an example there, suggesting to use `dynamic`.