# TempData does not contains any definition

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem in regarding my `TempData["Something"]` because I want to customize every content of the `Something`.  Below is my code:

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLoanContract(ModelLoan lc, string message)
    {
        var myList = new ModelLoan();
        var countLoan =  _Context.LoanContract.Count(c => c.EmployeeId == lc.loanContract.EmployeeId && c.LoanTypeId == lc.loanContract.LoanTypeId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //Some Logic
                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = new { CssClassName = "alert-success", Title = "Success!", Message = "You have successfully applied.  Please wait for confirmation.  Thank you!" };

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
    }
```

**View:**

```html
@if(TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert @TempData["SuccessMessage"].CssClassName">
        <strong>@TempData["SuccessMessage"].Title</strong> @TempData["SuccessMessage"].Message
    </div>

}
```

But I got an error on some objects `CssClassName`, `Title`, `Message` in `TempData["SuccessMessage"]` and I don't have any idea yet why.  I know there is a small trick to fix this.  Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Find your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908189

Comment: 1. What error did you get? 2. Your controller should not be deciding the `CSS` classes because that is the concern of the view. 3. Your controller should not be deciding what error message to show to user because that is the concern of the view. 4. You should pass a model to your view and then in your view decide what css and message to show.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot store anonymous type into `TempData` but you can create a class and convert `tempdata` to the class like this

```
public class ClsMsg
{
           public string CssClassName { get; set; }
           public string Title { get; set; }
           public string Message  { get; set; }

}
```

in action

```
TempData["SuccessMessage"] = new ClsMsg { CssClassName = "alert-success", Title = "Success!", Message = "You have successfully applied.  Please wait for confirmation.  Thank you!" };
```

and in view

```
 @if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
{

    ClsMsg msg = TempData["SuccessMessage"] as ClsMsg;


    <div class="alert @msg.CssClassName">
        <strong>@msg.Title</strong> @msg.Message
    </div>


}
```